# Create Components automatically to the 'Selected' JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jtabbedpane

I have written a code, given below.
Here, I have a tabbed panel where I am adding more Tabs with '+'(add tab sign) like gChrome in right side of the Frame. I have another fixed panel in the left side of the Frame, which consists of some Buttons. 
My query:

**1.** Now I want to add some components into the specific tabbed panels (panel 1 or panel 2 ..) by using Button Action from another Panel. How can I do this. Afterwards I need to save each tabbed panel's all components list in a script.
Any suggestion please.

**2.** If you run the code, you can see in output that the right tabbed panels are very narrow in size, may be for using BorderLayout.LINE_END. And if I extend my GUI, the panels remain same size.
I want to fixed the narrow size of the tab panels, and I want the size of the tab panels will be increasing also with the increasing of Frame.

Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TestTabSelection extends JFrame {

    public JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
    public JPanel editPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton MM, CM, AAA, VO;

    public TestTabSelection() {


        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
                panel1.setSize(600, 550);
                JPanel createAll = new JPanel();
                createAll.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                createAll.BorderLayout.LINE_END;

                tab.addTab("CreateAll", createAll);
                tab.addTab("Slice 1", panel1);
                tab.addTab("+", new JPanel());
                tab.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    private int lastSelected;
                    private boolean ignore = false;

                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        if (!ignore) {
                            ignore = true;
                            try {
                                int selected = tab.getSelectedIndex();
                                String title = tab.getTitleAt(selected);
                                if ("+".equals(title)) {
                                    JPanel pane = CreateSlice();
                                    tab.insertTab("Slice "
                                            + (tab.getTabCount()), null, pane,
                                            null, lastSelected + selected);
                                    tab.setSelectedComponent(pane);
                                } else {
                                    lastSelected = selected;
                                }
                            } finally {
                                ignore = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });



                final JButton btn = new JButton("Add");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println(tab.getTabCount());
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setTitle("Network Slice Creation");
                frame.setSize(1000, 700);
                frame.setBackground(Color.gray);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                createPanel0();
                frame.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                frame.add(tab,BorderLayout.LINE_END);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createPanel0() {

        editPanel = new JPanel(null);
        editPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(330, 650));
        editPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        editPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory
                .createTitledBorder("Netowrk Functions"));
        // editPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // FunctionHandler handler = new FunctionHandler();

        MM = new JButton("MM");
        MM.setBounds(50, 80, 150, 40);
        MM.setVisible(true);
        // MM.addActionListener(handler);

        AAA = new JButton("AAA");
        AAA.setBounds(50, 160, 150, 40);
        AAA.setVisible(true);
        // AAA.addActionListener(handler);

        CM = new JButton("CM");
        CM.setBounds(50, 240, 150, 40);
        CM.setVisible(true);
//      CM.addActionListener(handler);

        VO = new JButton("VO");
        VO.setBounds(50, 320, 150, 40);
        VO.setVisible(true);
        /* VO.addActionListener(handler); */

        editPanel.add(MM);
        editPanel.add(AAA);
        editPanel.add(CM);
        editPanel.add(VO);

    }

    public JPanel CreateSlice() {

        JPanel pane = new JPanel(null);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 600));
        return pane;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTabSelection();
    }

}
```

[LayOut needs to be corrected (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1gOF.png)

[Target Action (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8kTo.png)

Comment: You second assumption is correct, you'd need to use a different layout manager

Comment: Which layout is better, if I extend my frame so that the right panel will also be extended along with frame ?@MadProgrammer

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Can you also give me any idea for the first point ? I am hoping to get your idea. I can use ChangeListener for the tab, but I need to exclude '+' tab selection, I tried but couldnt get success.

Comment: The layout which is better is the one which meets your needs, perhaps try playing around with `GridBagLayout`

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, It works.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution,
Need a global variable, `int index`, 
in stateChanged method, `index = e.getSource().getselectedIndex();`
I Saved each Panel in a ArrayList (PanelList), 
Then actionPerformed by any button to create component to that selected JTabbedPane, will be

```
PanelList.get(index).add(button);
```

It gets the JTabbedPane which I select and add Component in it.